# colcon build package blacklist

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a ros2 workspace with colcon.
How I can blacklist packages?

I am looking for the catkin-equivalent to:

```
catkin config --blacklist baz
```

--- updated information --

I tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
$ colcon build --packages-skip mypackage

usage: colcon [-h] [--log-base LOG_BASE] [--log-level LOG_LEVEL] {build,test,test-result} ...
colcon: error: unrecognized arguments: --packages-skip mypackage
```

also tried unsuccessfully:

```
$ colcon build --packages-ignore mypackage

usage: colcon [-h] [--log-base LOG_BASE] [--log-level LOG_LEVEL] {build,test,test-result} ...
colcon: error: unrecognized arguments: --packages-ignore mypackage
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363749/colcon-build-package-blacklist/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-10-20**:
Do you have the Debian package `python3-colcon-package-selection` or the Python package `colcon-package-selection` installed?

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2020-10-20**:
Nopes. That was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's `--packages-skip baz` which might serve your purposes. See the docs [for lots more including and excluding options](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/package-selection-arguments.html).

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-10-20**:
`--packages-ignore` could also be an option: see https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/discovery-arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`COLCON_IGNORE` may be useful.
Once you set it, you can blacklist a package until you unblacklist it.

ref: https://answers.ros.org/question/299729/ament-versus-colcon-ignore-files/

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1